# how to button on click takes all the content from textarea, runs a function and then displays the final value inside new div?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm in the learning stages, can you please give me the answer with the explanation.

Also if possible, I would appreciate it if you could explain to me what I have done wrong here and then also show me the better way of doing it.

```js
//ARROW FUNCTION
const reverseNumber = num => (num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));



let textAreaEl = document.querySelector('#text-area');
let submitButtonEl = document.querySelector('#output-button');
let outputAreaEl = document.querySelector('#output');


submitButtonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  textAreaValue = reverseNumber(textAreaEl)
  outputAreaEl.innerHTML = textAreaValue.value;
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="object" title="object">JavaScript function that returns a passed string with letters in alphabetical order</label>
  <textarea id="text-area" name="object-name" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="RETURN" id="return-value" />
  <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I see no question here... What is your problem? If you don't have a problem and just want your code reviewed, [there's an SE site for that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please see the title now.

Comment: Here's your code fixed, mostly basic typo type errors: https://jsfiddle.net/ao2qdtzc/ Mind to properly reference your actual `id`s in your JS code, and also the difference between an element and its `.value` or `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no element with `#output-button`. You need to fix that.

You are passing the element itself to the `reverseNumber()`, you should pass the value to function.

I will also suggest you use `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if the text is plain text (not *htmlString*).

**Demo:**

```js
const reverseNumber = num => (num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));

let textAreaEl = document.querySelector('#text-area');
let submitButtonEl = document.querySelector('#output-button');
let outputAreaEl = document.querySelector('#output');

submitButtonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textAreaValue = reverseNumber(textAreaEl.value); //pass value here  
    outputAreaEl.textContent = textAreaValue; //no need to use value here
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="object" title="object">JavaScript function that returns a passed string with letters in alphabetical order</label>
  <textarea id="text-area" name="object-name" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="RETURN" id="output-button"/>   <!--fix the id here-->
  <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: For the record: this is 99% sloppiness on OP's part, not really a programming problem. I don't see how any of this is a useful addition to this website. Posting an answer here encourages people to just skip basic debugging and go straight to SO, which will make this website completely unusable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all textarea id is incorrect so querySelector is returning undefined and click event is not attached. I have corrected the button id in html.

You need to use `textAreaEl.value` to find the textarea text and pass it to reverseNumber function.

```js
//ARROW FUNCTION
const reverseNumber = num => (num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));



let textAreaEl = document.querySelector('#text-area');
let submitButtonEl = document.querySelector('#output-button');
let outputAreaEl = document.querySelector('#output');


submitButtonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textAreaValue = reverseNumber(textAreaEl.value)  
    outputAreaEl.innerHTML=textAreaValue;
});
```

```html
 <form action="">
        <label for="object" title="object">JavaScript function that reverses a number</label>
        <textarea id="text-area" name="object-name" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="RETURN" id="output-button"/>   
        <div id="output"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be like this

```
const reverseNumber = num => (num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
console.log(reverseNumber(54321));

let textAreaEl = document.querySelector('#text-area');
let submitButtonEl = document.querySelector('#return-value');
let outputAreaEl = document.querySelector('#output');

submitButtonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let textAreaValue = reverseNumber(textAreaEl.value);  
    outputAreaEl.innerHTML = textAreaValue;
});
```

First, your `document.querySelector('#output-button')` is not match with `<input type="button" value="RETURN" id="return-value"/>`.

Second, you have to use variable declaration keyword to get `textAreaEl.value`

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer